# Android Jetpack Compose: Can't set backgroundColor for OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose, and trying to set backgroundColor to an OutlinedTextField.

This is my code

```
fun MyTextField() {
    Column(Modifier
        .background(Color.Gray)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = "text",
            onValueChange = {},
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.White, // does not work
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Red,
                textColor = Color.Red
            ),
            // modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White) - works but not as I expected
        )
    }
}
```

The `backgroundColor = Color.White` does not work at all. The OutlinedTextField stays transparent:

[image]

When using the `modifier` the background is changed, but also the part reserved for Label, even when I don't have a label:

[image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: If you check the source code, the `OutlinedTextFieldLayout` just ignores the `backgroundColor`. I don't know if is intended

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'll leave my answer here because I didn't find an easier way...

You can define a composable which will work as wrapper+background.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldBackground(
    color: Color,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    // This box just wraps the background and the OutlinedTextField
    Box {
        // This box works as background
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .padding(top = 8.dp) // adding some space to the label
                .background(
                    color, 
                    // rounded corner to match with the OutlinedTextField
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp) 
                )
        )
        // OutlineTextField will be the content...
        content()
    }
}
```

Then you just need to wrap your `OutlinedTextField` with it.

```kotlin
OutlinedTextFieldBackground(Color.LightGray) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = textState.value,
        onValueChange = { textState.value = it },
        label = {
            Text(
                text = "Name"
            )
        },
    )
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

As you can see, it works. But as mentioned by [Sergey Krivenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2078368/sergey-krivenkov) it could be a bad choice in terms of design, because half of the label has one background and other part has another background and this could looks strange.

Comment: Your attached image shows why backgroundColor doesn't work on OutlinedTextField. Because there is a gap in the border and it looks strange - half of label has one background and other part has another background.
Or it's just a bug))

Comment: I agree :) I'm just providing a viable solution :P

Comment: I edited my answer with your comment @SergeyKrivenkov. Thanks!

Comment: Thanx for a working solution. Regarding the "2 backgrounds for the label" I wanted to use it only with placeholder text and without a label, because of this issue.

Comment: Are there any canonical solution for this already?

Answer (score 17):

**Update:**

As *@Blundell* correctly noted, `TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors` [has become deprecated](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults.kt;drc=b72e2f25b72149fc9d613a28bbe7608ee8091646;l=1152) and is currently recommended to be replaced with [`OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults.kt;drc=b72e2f25b72149fc9d613a28bbe7608ee8091646;l=1479).
The main difference between `colors` and `outlinedTextFieldColors` is that now three separate components are used, instead of one `containerColor` — [`focusedContainerColor`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults.kt;drc=b72e2f25b72149fc9d613a28bbe7608ee8091646;l=1485), [`unfocusedContainerColor`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults.kt;drc=b72e2f25b72149fc9d613a28bbe7608ee8091646;l=1486) and [`disabledContainerColor`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults.kt;drc=b72e2f25b72149fc9d613a28bbe7608ee8091646;l=1487).

The following code will be relevant for now:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextFieldDefaults
...
OutlinedTextField(
    ...
    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
        unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White,
        disabledContainerColor = Color.White
    ),
```

**Old answer:**

When using the **material** library, your code builds without problems.

```
import androidx.compose.material.TextFieldDefaults
...
OutlinedTextField(
    ...
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        backgroundColor = Color.White
    ),
```

However, if **material3** is used, then the [`TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TextFieldDefaults.kt;drc=b72e2f25b72149fc9d613a28bbe7608ee8091646;l=1155) does not have a [`backgroundColor`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/TextFieldDefaults.kt;drc=1f4daf44e9bf883c7d87dd4ef39a5bf954a0a0c9;l=438) parameter.
In order to achieve correct display on **material3**, just replace `backgroundColor` with `containerColor`.

```
import androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldDefaults
...
OutlinedTextField(
    ...
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        containerColor = Color.White
    ),
```

Comment: This is the only way I was able to set the background color for the edit field and leave the error text background unchanged. Thanks!

Comment: seems its now `focusedContainerColor` & `unfocusedContainerColor` for M3

Answer (score 4):

I found this

```
Row(
        Modifier
            .background(
                colorResource(id = R.color.col_EEEEEE)
            )
            .align(BottomEnd)
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp).background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(22.dp)),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(22.dp),
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.caption
        )
    }
```

In the above code, I added required background color with the shape in the modifier. The modifier shape property is the same as the `OutlinedTextField` shape property, which gives required effect.

[image: image to refer]

Comment: **Note:** Add the required color in `colors.xml` file under the `res/values` folder.
E.g. `<color name="col_EEEEEE">#EEEEEE</color>`

Answer (score 3):

You have to do like this

```
OutlinedTextField(
                ...
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        backgroundColor =Color.White
                    )
                )
```

in order to set background Outline textfield

Comment: No such parameter anymore in Material3. Use `containerColor` instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
TextField(
...
colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                    focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                )
...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use following TextFiledDefaults.textFieldColors properties to change background color

```
     OutlinedTextField(
         value = exampleName ?: "",
         onValueChange = onExampleChange,
         colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                textColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                disabledTextColor = Color.Transparent,
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = modifier,
                value = text,
                label = label,
                onValueChange = {
                 text=it
                },
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        backgroundColor =Color.White
                    )
                )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: textFieldColors() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check this screenshot]

Check this screenshot to give background to OutlinedTextField in compose

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where adding a box behind the `OutlinedTextField` caused it to behave based on the expand state of its label. Additionally, when attempting to add a rounded view behind the label, there was a noticeable gap between it and the `OutlinedTextField`. I came up with a somewhat inelegant solution to this problem, but I hope it proves helpful to you.

```
modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
    drawRoundRect(Color.Gray, cornerRadius = CornerRadius(0.dp.toPx()), topLeft = Offset(40F,30F), size = Size(140F, 40F))
}
```

Have to change `topLeft` and `cornerRadius` values which is suits to your `outlinedTextField` size.
[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV3WC.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
TextField(
        value = user, { text -> user = text },

        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp)
            .padding(start = 64.dp, end = 64.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
            .background(color = Color.White)
            .border(
                1.dp, color = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#7d32a8")),

                shape = RoundedCornerShape(50)


            ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#7d32a8")),
            fontSize = 14.sp
        ),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            containerColor = Color.White // here add containerColor not backgroundColor

// backgroundColor is not working !!!

        ),


        )
```